# How to make a view like Recents in the Phone application for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, sdk, view

I need to make a view just like Recents in the Phone application. There are two connected buttons on the top, and when either one is clicked, the view below will change. I tried to use UIToolbar but there are spaces between buttons. Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks in advance.

-Joey

Answer (score 3):

I think you want a UISegmentedControl. It allows for connected buttons like the one in the Phone application. Add it to a UIToolbar if you want to mimic the Phone app exactly.

The [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html) has more info.

Comment: Additionally, you can use the standard UINavigationBar and add it to the view in the middle. Ask if you need elaboration.